# How to disable walking through walls in Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

This is my player:

```
self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[self.spriteAtlas textureNamed:@"idle_0"]];
self.player.texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
self.player.position = self.map.spawnPoint;
self.player.name = @"Character";
self.player.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
self.player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.player.texture.size];
self.player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypePlayer;
self.player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypeExit;
self.player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypeWall;
self.player.zPosition = 100;
```

and this is my walls:

```
SKNode *wall = [SKNode node];
wall.name = @"wall";
wall.position = CGPointMake(position.x + size.width * 0.5f - 0.5f * self.tileSize,
                          position.y - size.height * 0.5f + 0.5f * self.tileSize);
wall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:size];
wall.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
wall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypeWall;
wall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypePlayer;
wall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypePlayer;
```

And what i'm trying to do is to move to tapped location. In touchesBegan method I run moveTo action with coordinates from tapped location. And if there's a wall between tapped location and character it just goes right through.

I tried stopping movement when touch with wall begins, but that's seems to be not the right solution becouse if for example path is as wide as player himself and that path is surrounded by walls it can't walk through because of collision with walls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop moving your character using SKAction.  Most people try to implement their entire game mechanic using actions while actions are really meant for one-off animations.  Action's aren't flexible.  Once you tell your character to move, he's going to move no matter what's in the way.

Try using your update method in your scene and setting your characters velocity to the the direction of your touch.  Here's some pseudo code..  I don't have xcode running at the moment, but you'll get the gist.  We're only accounting for left and right movement here.

```
var touch: CGPoint?

func touchesBegan(thisTouch){
    touch = thisTouch.location
}

func update(currentTime) {
    if let moveToTouch = touch {
        if moveToTouch.x > player.position.x {
            player.position.x += 1
        }

        else if moveToTouch.x < player.position.x {
            player.position.y -= 1
        }

        // check how far we are from our destination.  if we reached our destination then we stop
        let distance = sqrt(player.position.x * moveToTouch.x + player.position.y * moveToTouch.y)
        if distance < 1.0 {
            moveToTouch = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried implementing it and everything kinda looks okay, except for when moving up or down in narrow path (when player is between walls) players texture gets like a shaky effect. Maybe it has something to do with collisions and physics. idk.

Comment: Stop the player when he's close to a wall